# Replace on load content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change content unicode with icons on load, but it does not work because I'm loading content with jQuery after the page loads. I use this code:

This is "custom.js" file.

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();

    $(function() {





            var canRun = false;
            $.ajax({
                    url: './includes/loadfeed.php',
                    cache: false,
                    beforeSend: function(){
                    $('#tiles').append('<li id="loadingimg"><img src="images/loading.gif" width="80" height="80" style="margin:auto;" /></li>');
                    },
                    success: function(html){
                        $('#tiles').append(html);
                        $('#loadingimg').remove();
                        canRun = true;

                      }

               });



                    $(window).scroll(function() {
                    if( ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 10 ) && (canRun == true ) ) {

                        canRun = false; 
                        var newCount    = $('#next_id').data('newcount');
                        var maxid       = $('#next_id').data('maxid');

                        $.ajax({
                          type: 'GET',
                          url: '/includes/loadfeed.php?next',
                          data: { newcount: newCount, max_id: maxid },
                          dataType: "text",
                          cache: false,
                          beforeSend: function(){
                          $('#tiles').append('<li id="loadingimg"><img src="images/loading.gif" width="80" height="80" style="margin:auto;" /></li>');
                          $('#next_id').remove();
                          },
                          success: function(xxx){
                                $('#loadingimg').remove();
                                $('#tiles').append(xxx);
                                canRun = true; 
                            }
                          });
                        }

            }); });
```

And this is replace code. "getomeji" have in loaded content.

```
$(document).on('load','#getemoji',function(){
var el = $(this).get(0);
el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(
new RegExp(ranges.join('|'), 'g'), 
'<span class="emoji" data-emoji="$&"></span>'
);  
});
```

This code is working with "click" events but not working with "on load". Can someone help me?

Comment: are you sure you include that code after you include jquery??

Comment: Do you have this code inside of a document ready? If so then you don't need the on load, If you don't have a dom ready though, the script might not be seeing your span's. What does `el` show when you console.log it? Where are you initalizing your javascript? In head or in the body?

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef yes i did. i use $.ajax function first then after other code. its working with click event

Comment: @ShanRobertson i run this code in same custom.js file.

Comment: you can provide your working click event that will explain better what you trying to do

Comment: var $ = jQuery.noConflict(); <-- HUH? Why?

Answer (score 0):

How about doing it as document is ready ...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#getemoji").replace(
    new RegExp(ranges.join('|'), 'g'), 
    '<span class="emoji" data-emoji="$&"></span>'
  );  
});
```

Comment: javascript `onevent` methods are for creating inline events. `addEventListener` just uses the event name like `load` or `click`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
         url: './includes/loadfeed.php',
         cache: false,
         beforeSend: function(){
                    $('#tiles').append('<li id="loadingimg"><img src="images/loading.gif" width="80" height="80" style="margin:auto;" /></li>');
                      },
          success: function(html){
                    $('#tiles').append(html);
                    $('#loadingimg').remove();
                            canRun = true;
                    $('#getemoji').load(function(){
                       var el = $(this).get(0);
                       el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(
                       new RegExp(ranges.join('|'), 'g'), 
                       '<span class="emoji" data-emoji="$&"></span>'
                        );  
                    });

                    }

     });

  });
```

Comment: your updated code is good and I think this is nothing wrong in it.. What error you got?? did you get Undefined variables in your inspect elements when page load??

Answer (score 0):

i found answer.

```
$("#tiles").contents().each(function () {
                                if (this.nodeType === 3) this.nodeValue = $.trim($(this).text()).replace(new RegExp(ranges.join('|'), 'g'),'<span class="emoji" data-emoji="$&"></span>')
                                if (this.nodeType === 1) $(this).html( $(this).html().replace(new RegExp(ranges.join('|'), 'g'),'<span class="emoji" data-emoji="$&"></span>'))
});
```

Best regards for your comments.